# difference of array element equal to difference of bitwise or and bitwise and

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

Given a sequence A of n integers: we have to find the number of pairs `(i,j)` where

```
(A[i] | A[j]) - (A[i] & A[j]) = (A[i] - A[j])
```

For example suppose A is {4,4,2,1} so total 6 pairs exist

```
(1,1)
(2,2)
(1,2)
(2,1)
(3,3)
(4,4)
```

I am getting tle in my code. Can anyone suggest a better approach for this question?

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
#define mod 1000000007

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        ll n;
        cin >> n;

        vector<ll> v1;
        ll i, a, j;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> a;
            v1.push_back(a);
        }
        ll sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                ll pp = v1[i] | v1[j];
                ll qq = v1[i] & v1[j];
                ll rr = v1[i] - v1[j];

                if ((pp - qq) == rr)
                {
//                  cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
                    sum++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << sum << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Given two numbers X and Y, the statement `(X | Y) - (X & Y) = (X - Y)` is true if and only if `(X | Y) == X` and `(X & Y) == Y`. Since the OR of two numbers is greater than or equal than either number, and the AND of two numbers is less than or equal to either number, it follows that X must be greater than or equal to Y, and every bit set in Y must also be set in X.

Comment: @user3386109 for a given sequence of n integers, is it possible to do in O(n) time.?

Comment: @user3386109 i am asking with respect to code approach

Comment: I don't think it's possible in O(n). I'd start by sorting the array, which takes O(nlogn) time. BTW, what is the maximum size of the array? And what is the maximum value of an element in the array?

Comment: @user3386109 10^5 is maximimum size